# Laravel 8 bearer token exception handling if bearer token not found

Tags: php, laravel, api, bearer-token

Hello I can't understand how to set error message when user put some wrong bearer token currently I am not getting any exceptional error message if I try wrong bearer token in postman.

```
public function general_information(Request $request) {
    try {
        return $token = $request->bearerToken();
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        return $e->message();
    }
}
```

Comment: So if you're not trying to handle an `Exception` you'll need to parse some string for an error message maybe? What are the conditions of failure?

Comment: I am using laravel sanctum api 
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']], function () {

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`
add this function and change the message as you want

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'haha'], 401);
    }

    return redirect()->guest('login');
}
```

here return **haha** message

note define this before write the function
`Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;`

Comment: its redirecting me on 404 page but now showing any exception.

Comment: because you don't have login page .. so delete this ` return redirect()->guest('login');` and write ` return response()->json("some message");`